# How to accumulate the number of unique row values per ID through time

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset consisting of a date, car_id and destination.

For every row, I want the accumulated number of unique destinations for every car_id. It is important that the counter starts at the earliest date.

The desired output is the column "unique_destinations":

```
          date  car_id   destination  unique_destinations
0   01/01/2019       1        Boston                    1
1   01/01/2019       2         Miami                    1
2   02/01/2019       1        Boston                    1
3   02/01/2019       2       Orlando                    2
4   03/01/2019       1      New York                    2
5   03/01/2019       2         Tampa                    3
6   04/01/2019       1        Boston                    2
7   04/01/2019       2         Miami                    3
8   05/01/2019       1    Washington                    3
9   05/01/2019       2  Jacksonville                    4
10  06/01/2019       1      New York                    3
11  06/02/2019       2       Atlanta                    5
```

Comment: can you explain the rows 0,2,6.. and their unique destinations..how did you come to that

Comment: @iamklaus Boston is the same, so its not +1 for unique destinations.

Comment: @jezrael your help is required.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay this might not be efficient but its an approach :)

```
def check(data):
    seen = []
    flag = 0
    for index,row in data.iterrows():
        if row['destination'] not in seen:
            flag+=1
            data['unique_destinations'][index] = flag
            seen.append(row['destination'])
        else:
            data['unique_destinations'][index] = flag
    return data

df['unique_destinations'] = 0
df.groupby('car_id').apply(check)
```

**Output**

```
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     2
4     2
5     3
6     2
7     3
8     3
9     4
10    3
11    5
Name: unique_destinations, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also split our data by car ids and then run a self defined function like the following:

```
def create_uniques(df):
    dests = []
    uniques = []
    counter = 0
    for ix, r in df.iterrows():
        if r['destination'] not in dests:
            counter += 1
            dests.append(r['destination'])
            uniques.append(counter)
        else:
            uniques.append(counter)

    df['unique_destinations'] = uniques

    return df

df1 = df[df['car_id'] == 1].reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = df[df['car_id'] == 2].reset_index(drop=True)

df_final = pd.concat([create_uniques(df1), create_uniques(df2)], ignore_index=True).sort_values('date')
```

Output:

```
print(df_final)
         date  car_id   destination  unique_destinations
0  2019-01-01       1        Boston                    1
6  2019-01-01       2         Miami                    1
1  2019-02-01       1        Boston                    1
7  2019-02-01       2       Orlando                    2
2  2019-03-01       1      New York                    2
8  2019-03-01       2         Tampa                    3
3  2019-04-01       1        Boston                    2
9  2019-04-01       2         Miami                    3
4  2019-05-01       1    Washington                    3
10 2019-05-01       2  Jacksonville                    4
5  2019-06-01       1      New York                    3
11 2019-06-02       2       Atlanta                    5
```

**Timings** with other answers:
*Erfans* answer:

```
%%timeit

def create_uniques(df):
    dests = []
    uniques = []
    counter = 0
    for ix, r in df.iterrows():
        if r['destination'] not in dests:
            counter += 1
            dests.append(r['destination'])
            uniques.append(counter)
        else:
            uniques.append(counter)

    df['unique_destinations'] = uniques

    return df

df1 = df[df['car_id'] == 1].reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = df[df['car_id'] == 2].reset_index(drop=True)

df_final = pd.concat([create_uniques(df1), create_uniques(df2)], ignore_index=True).sort_values('date')

11 ms ± 211 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

*Iamklaus* answer:

```
%%timeit

def check(data):
    seen = []
    flag = 0
    for index,row in data.iterrows():
        if row['destination'] not in seen:
            flag+=1
            data['unique_destinations'][index] = flag
            seen.append(row['destination'])
        else:
            data['unique_destinations'][index] = flag
    return data

df['unique_destinations'] = 0
df.groupby('car_id').apply(check)

15.3 ms ± 346 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

*nikhilbalwani's* answer:

```
%%timeit
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    unique_before_date = df[df['date'] <= row['date']].groupby(['car_id'])['destination'].nunique()
    df['unique_destinations'][index] = int(unique_before_date[row['car_id']])

839 ms ± 17.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this short and sweet code:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    unique_before_date = df[df['date'] <= row['date']].groupby(['car_id'])['destination'].nunique()
    df['unique_destinations'][index] = int(unique_before_date[row['car_id']])

print(df)
```

It produces this output:

```
         date  car_id   destination unique_destinations
0  2019-01-01       1        Boston                   1
1  2019-01-01       2         Miami                   1
2  2019-01-02       1        Boston                   1
3  2019-01-02       2       Orlando                   2
4  2019-01-03       1      New York                   2
5  2019-01-03       2         Tampa                   3
6  2019-01-04       1        Boston                   2
7  2019-01-04       2         Miami                   3
8  2019-01-05       1    Washington                   3
9  2019-01-05       2  Jacksonville                   4
10 2019-01-06       1      New York                   3
11 2019-02-06       2       Atlanta                   5
```

Answer (score -1):

It is assuming here that you want to add +1 for every other day

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
df['unique destinations'] = ((df['date']) - min(df['date'])).dt.days + 1
```

But if you need to iterate only when you have a new day that do not necessarily follow one another, you can do this:

```
a = 1
unique_destinations = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    try:
        if row['date'] == currentdate:
            pass
        else:
            a = a + 1
    except:
        pass
    unique_destinations.append(a)
    currentdate = row['date']
df['unique_destinations'] = unique_destinations
```

Comment: No. I only want to add +1 if the destination for a specific car_id has not been seen before, hence is new/unique.

Comment: Test your output before posting an answer, this gives a complete different output than OP expected.

Comment: You are still not counting the number of unique destinations.